# All combinations of a row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, python-itertools

i have the following Dataframe (df = )  with around 40 mio rows.

```
No  Color
A   Red
A   Black
B   White
B   Orange
B   Green
C   Red
C   Green
D   Yellow
D   Orange
D   Green
```

i try to have the following output:

```
No  Color
A   Red
A   Black
B   White
B   Orange
B   White
B   Green
B   Orange 
B   Green
C   Red
C   Green
D   Yellow
D   Orange
D   Yellow
D   Green
D   Orange
D   Green
```

at first i thought to use itertools combinations,    it.combinations(Colors["Colors"],2), but the problem was, that it gives me the combinations of the whole column and don't correlate to the column "No".
The next try was to aggregate the whole dataframe to have all the needed combination in a list and only have about 5000 rows

from:

```
No Colors
A   Red, Black  
B   White, Orange, Green
C   Red, Green, Yellow
D   Orange, Green
```

to:

```
No  Colors              CombColors
A   Red,Black           Red, Black
B   White,Orange,Green  White, Orange, White, Green, Orange, Green
C   Red,Green,Yellow    Red, Green, Red, Yellow, Green, Yellow
D   Orange,Green        Orange, Green
```

with: `df.apply(lambda x: list(it.combinations(x,2), axis =1)` but this also doesn't work (all combinations in each row).

What is the right solution to achieve the wanted output (of attempt 1 or attempt 2)?

Edit: 1

if i try to use  `df.apply(lambda x: list(it.combinations(x,2), axis =1)` i generate following column

```
 No     Colors              CombColors
    A   Red,Black           [([Red, Black], [(['Red', 'Black'], ['White'..
    B   White,Orange,Green  [([White, Orange, Green], [(['Red', 'Black']...
    C   Red,Green,Yellow    [([Red, Green], [(['Red', 'Black'], ['White'...
    D   Orange,Green        [([Yellow, Orange, Green], [(['Red', 'Black']...
```

i think on problem is, i aggregate the Colors by a tuple or list (tuple is empty []). `df.groupby("No")["Color"].apply(list).agg(tuple).to_frame()`

nevertheless the itertool gives me a combination of every column.

Edit 2:
the solutions of alparslan mimaroğlu and Henry Vik work both and are (for me) astonishing. Till now i cannot understand the logic behind these, but i'll try! Thanks!

Comment: do you mind explaining the logic?

Comment: When you say attempt 2 "doesn't work", please can you describe what it does and how that falls short of what you would like it to do?

Comment: You want to execute something for every group of No's therefore I believe you can follow why we are using a groupby statement. To create the every unique combination you can use `itertools.combinations` as you know but you have to use it on the list of unique column values. Therefore you have to use ` .unique()`. If you group by and apply and return a series pandas creates an index and a column with the grouper and the returned value. You can check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) to understand more. If you have any questions let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby by No and create the lists you want quite easily.

```
def combinations(group): 
    return pd.Series(list(it.combinations(group['Color'].unique(), 2)))

df.groupby('No').apply(combinations).explode()
```

if you don't make it explode it will return you a list of color combinations

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use `groupby` and `agg`:

```
print (df.groupby("No").agg(Colors=("Color", ", ".join),
                            CombColors=("Color", lambda d: ", ".join(chain.from_iterable(combinations(d, 2))))))

                   Colors                                    CombColors
No                                                                     
A              Red, Black                                    Red, Black
B    White, Orange, Green    White, Orange, White, Green, Orange, Green
C              Red, Green                                    Red, Green
D   Yellow, Orange, Green  Yellow, Orange, Yellow, Green, Orange, Green
```